# Custom (group-)sorting of column in Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to understand the custom sorting mechanism in `Datatables`. What I'm trying to do is sorting a column according to its value and the value of other columns (conatining a group) to get groupwise sorting.

To do this I came accross the sorting plugin: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Just as an example (could be another) I had a look at the "anti-the" plugin. To actvate it I added:

```
targets = "_all", type = "anti-the"
```

to the `columnDefs`

and used

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "anti-the-pre": function ( a ) {
        console.log("pre");
        return a.replace(/^the /i, "");
    },

    "anti-the-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        console.log("asc");
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "anti-the-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        console.log("desc");
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

The plan is to adapt these three functions to get the desired grouped sorting.

1. Interestingly "pre" is printed to the console everytime when the table header is clicked (and the table is resorted). I expected "asc" and "desc" to be printed as well (in alterning order) but nothing is printed, why?
2. Is this the right approach to get the desired result of grouped sorting or do I need to define my own "orderDataType" to reach this?

**Edit:**

Just to make things a bit clearer:
Let's assume I have a table containing the information/columns about "department" and "floor" When sorting "floor" I'd like it to be sorted for floor for every department

before sorting:

|department|floor|

|IT|2|

|IT|1|

|Sales|1|

|Sales|2|

after click on header ("floor" -> asc)

|IT|1|

|IT|2|

|Sales|1|

|Sales|2|

click again (desc)

|IT|2|

|IT|1|

|Sales|2|

|Sales|1|

in the data I have there ist no mix between groups (here: departments) -> rows for the same department will be next to each other

Comment: If you are showing both columns your users can order two columns by simply pressing shift and clicking the header. No custom sorting needed in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to do a groupwise sorting of your data i would recommend you use datatables "orthagonal data" in combination with HTML5 data-* attributes

As you can read here ([Datatables Website - Orthagonal Data  - HTML5](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5)) using the custom attribute `data-order` should be your weapon of choice.

For example:

You want to group `department` and `floor` but only show `department` to the user. This example should show you the desired output

(The floornumber in the surname cell is a helper to visualise the right ordering and can be removed)

```
<table id="myTestTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th><th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="it 1">IT</td> <td>Daniel (1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="sales 2">sales</td> <td>Sue (2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="it 1">IT</td> <td>John (1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="it 2">IT</td> <td>Mr. Miyagi (2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="sales 2">sales</td> <td>Mel (2)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="sales 1">sales</td> <td>Marc (1)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $('#myTestTable').dataTable();
</script>
```

Edit:

The sorting in the first example would be wrong for floors 10 and above. It would be 1, 10, 2, 3, 4 and so on because datatables would strictly sort the string.

To address this issue there is a sorting plugin called [natural sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural) on the datatables website. Including this code and adding `{ columnDefs: [ { type: 'natural' , targets: 0 } ] }` to the tabledefinition will fix the sorting to a more `human` way.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'd like to use the clicked columns type. i.e. using your approach, IT in floor 11 (data-order = "it 11") would be ordered before IT located on floor 2 ("it 2"), wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would. In this case you would have to combine orthagonal data and custom sorting.

Comment: any hints where/how to start? (btw. I've added some more info as edit in the original question to make the problem a bit clearer)